# MyProductOptionImpl cannot be resolved to a type in broadleaf-admin

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi i have added the custom controller to admin. i followed following section in broadleaf docs

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/admin/entity-type-selection

but it will gives us the following error

MyProductOptionImpl cannot be resolved to a type in broadleaf-admin

at hook1 part ca you please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in Advance